# Ext JS 4 - How to control rowEditor inside controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to learn how can I controller rowEditor plugin inside controller..

Here's rowEditor definition:

```
Ext.define(appName + '.view.department.DepartmentGrid', {

    initComponent: function() {

       this.rowEditor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
          clicksToEdit: 2
       });

    }

}
```

** Controller**

```
this.control({
    'departmentgrid': {
        // ??
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-edit

```
this.control({
    'departmentgrid': {
        edit: this.onDepartmentGridEdit
    }
});
```

Comment: OK thanks, I thought maybe because of it's a plugin, it has another way to control like actioncolumn..

Comment: A plugin is an extension of your grid, so the events your plugin has, wil lautomatically be in your grid aswell.

Comment: Thanks Johan, this one worked for me. Just wondering where in the Ext JS doc were you able to see this information?

Comment: Hi Carlos, if u check the RowEditing plugin: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-edit