# To force beforeedit & edit both work in Controller?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I'm using Extjs 4.1.1. Because I follow MVC I decided to move 'edit' & 'beforeedit' functions (rowEditing plugin) from grid i.e:

```
listeners: {'edit': function(editor, e) {
    ...
    },'beforeedit': function(editor, e) {
    ...
    }}
```

and put it inside controller just like:
[Ext JS 4 - How to control rowEditor inside controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914525/ext-js-4-how-to-control-roweditor-inside-controller)

My new code looks like this:

```
init: function() {

    this.control({          

        'myGrid': {
            edit: this.onRowEdit
        },

        'myGrid': {
            beforeedit: this.onRowBeforeEdit
        },

    });

},

onRowEdit: function(editor, e) {
    ... // Fires only when 'beforeedit' not present in this.control
},

onRowBeforeEdit: function(editor, e) {
    ... // Always fires
},
```

Now, 'beforeedit' fires fine. My problem is that 'edit' fires only when 'beforeedit' is not present. Anyone had same problem? Of course old grid listener like way worked fine for both.

**EDIT**
I've just observed that if I define 'beforedit' first and 'edit' second in this.control(), the  'beforeedit' is the one which is not firing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them in the same selector:

```
init: function() {

    this.control({          

        'myGrid': {
            edit: this.onRowEdit,
            beforeedit: this.onRowBeforeEdit
        }    
    });

}
```

It's the same problem if I would be doing this:

```
var name = {
   first: 'John',
   first: 'Doe'
};
alert(name.first); //will show a messagebox with 'Doe'
```